# I need to reword "best face forward"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

What is another word/phrase for "best face forward"?

Example usage:

> What first attracts us to a business is its visual appeal— so why not present your business with its best face forward?

Comment: Erm... *"best **face** forward"* isn't a known expression in the first place (there's also *"put a **brave face** on"*). The standard version is *"best **foot** forward"*. Was there anything else you wanted to know?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What would be a synonym for "best face forward"? How else can I say "best face forward"?

Comment: @S N: I can't really answer that - like I said, *"best face forward"* is not a known English expression, so I can only guess at what you intend it to mean.

Comment: @FF Isn't this another of your mangled idioms (which are thus usually non-idioms)? Apparently, 'You have heard the expression, "Putting Your Best Face Forward" ' (according to [Ezine Articles](http://EzineArticles.com/275025)). But I wouldn't rate this as as convincing an authority as OED.

Comment: "What first attracts us to a business is its visual appeal— so why not present your business with its best face forward?"

Comment: @FumbleFingers [It's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=best+face+forward&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbest%20face%20forward%3B%2Cc0) out there.

Comment: And just as Nessus can put his best foot forward, so can Janus put his better face forward.

Comment: What @Sven said (or at least *implied*, I assume). OP's example strikes me as laughably unlikely, given the "two-faced/Janus" allusions. But apparently [it's not totally unknown](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=best+face+forward%2Cbest+foot+forward&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbest%20face%20forward%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbest%20foot%20forward%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Put your best face forward," used when referring to one's appearance, is a current saying, no doubt a play on the traditional "put your best foot forward." I don't see a problem applying it to a business when treferring to its visual appeal. It is a good extension or use of the saying, which is normally used within the realm of fashion, attire, modelling, make up, etc.

As for another word or phrase, how about

**Present your business in its best light.**

This also uses a known saying, *in its best light.*

Comment: I certainly see a problem with it. It appears to be a mixed metaphor with "best foot forward", and "two-faced". Now a two-faced business probably should always try to put their best face forward I suppose...

Comment: I think most people misunderstood my question. All I asked was to reword "best face forward".

Answer (score 1):

A more established expression, mentioned at [wiki answers](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_meaning_of_the_idiom_'to_put_your_best_foot_forward'), is

> show your better side

Answer (score -1):

**put on a brave face**
to act confident in a difficult situation or put up a brave front.

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+on+a+brave+face